# Spark Streaming using Azure Event Hubs

Tags: azure, spark-streaming, azure-hdinsight, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

We use spark-streaming-eventhubs to read data from the IoTHub in our Spark Streaming application. I am trying to understand whether the offset and lease management is completely handled by this library? 
In [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shanyu/2015/09/18/understanding-and-using-hdinsight-spark-streaming/) blog post it says:

> ...by design each EventHubsReceiver instance only handles one Event Hubs partition. Each receiver instance requires one CPU core to run, and you need to leave some CPU cores to process the received data. So if you set partition count to N in Event Hubs parameters, you need to make sure you assign 2xN CPU cores to the streaming application.

So does it mean that the library will automatically create one receiver per partition and also manage leases?
Will it automatically write checkpoints into the checkpoint location?

It also says we need 2xN CPU cores assigned to the streaming application. So one would need 8 CPU cores if there are 4 Partitions in the IoTHub, is it really correct? Would it then make sense to create applications that can handle multiple use cases and output to multiple locations instead of one streaming application per use case / location?

In the latter case, e.g. having 3 application which read from the same IoTHub (4 partitions) we would need 24 cores which is expensive...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you are referring to [this library](https://github.com/hdinsight/spark-eventhubs) - we support lease management and replaying from Offset completely with in the library (i.e.,the Library creates one receiver per partition and manages leases and checkpoint location per partition).

We Apologize about the CPU story - which is no longer applicable - in that article - to give some background - we had 2 EventHubs-to-SPARK adapter efforts that went on - after a while we recognized that and consolidated them. You are looking at an article which refers to the deprecated EventHubs effort - which is out-dated - we will get that fixed.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. Is there a recommendation regarding the CPU cores count?